# MissingStubError: 'update' No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call: update

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito, dart-null-safety

I'm following a tutorial for a messaging app using flutter & it's connecting to rethinkdb. I'm trying to follow along with the latest packages and versions. I'm on a section where the author is using mockito for testing. I'm getting an error. I'm a beginner so the error is likely to be something very simple that I'm missing.

Here is the code snippet that is giving me an error:

```
test('should perform database update on messages', () async {
    //arrange
    final localMessage = LocalMessage('1234', message, ReceiptStatus.sent);
    when(database.update('messages', localMessage.toMap(),
            where: anyNamed('where'), whereArgs: anyNamed('whereArgs')))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => 1);

    //act
    await sut.updateMessage(localMessage);

    //assert
    verify(database.update('messages', localMessage.toMap(),
            where: anyNamed('where'),
            whereArgs: anyNamed('whereArgs'),
            conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace))
        .called(1);
  });
```

The error:

```
MissingStubError: 'update'
No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call:
update('messages', {chat_id: 1234, id: 4444, from: 111, to: 222, timestamp: 2021-04-01 00:00:00.000, contents: hey, receipt: sent}, {where: id = ?, whereArgs: [4444], conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace})

Add a stub for this method using Mockito's 'when' API, or generate the MockDatabase mock with a MockSpec with 'returnNullOnMissingStub: true' (see https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/annotations/MockSpec-class.html).
```

I'm confused by the last sentence, because it looks like there already is a 'when' being used. I want to try 'returnNullOnMissingStub: true', but what is the best place to add that in my code, and is it the right solution or is something else better?

I'm also confused because in the rest of the test file, I successfully use database.insert and database.query, so it seems strange to me that database.update wouldn't be working?

Here is the whole test file:

```
import 'package:chat/chat.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:rethink_chat/data/datasources/sqflite_datasource.dart';
import 'package:rethink_chat/models/chat.dart';
import 'package:rethink_chat/models/local_message.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

import 'sqflite_datasource_test.mocks.dart';

//class MockSqfliteDatabase extends Mock implements Database {}

@GenerateMocks([Database])

//class MockBatch extends Mock implements Batch {}

@GenerateMocks([Batch])
void main() {
  late SqfliteDatasource sut;
  late MockDatabase database; // late MockSqfliteDatabase database;
  late MockBatch batch;

  setUp(() {
    database = MockDatabase(); // database = MockSqfliteDatabase();
    batch = MockBatch();
    sut = SqfliteDatasource(database);
  });

  final message = Message.fromJson({
    'from': '111',
    'to': '222',
    'contents': 'hey',
    'timestamp': DateTime.parse("2021-04-01"),
    'id': '4444',
  });

  test('should perform insert of chat to the database', () async {
    //arrange
    final chat = Chat('1234');

    when(database.insert('chats', chat.toMap(),
            conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => 1);
    //act
    await sut.addChat(chat);
    //assert
    verify(database.insert('chats', chat.toMap(),
            conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace))
        .called(1);
  });

  test('should perform insert of message to the database', () async {
    //arrange
    final localMessage = LocalMessage('1234', message, ReceiptStatus.sent);

    when(database.insert('messages', localMessage.toMap(),
            conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => 1);
    //act
    await sut.addMessage(localMessage);

    //assert
    verify(database.insert('messages', localMessage.toMap(),
            conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace))
        .called(1);
  });

  test('should perform a database query and return message', () async {
    //arrange
    final messagesMap = [
      {
        'chat_id': '111',
        'id': '4444',
        'from': '111',
        'to': '222',
        'contents': 'hey',
        'receipt': 'sent',
        'timestamp': DateTime.parse("2021-04-01"),
      }
    ];
    when(database.query(
      'messages',
      where: anyNamed('where'),
      whereArgs: anyNamed('whereArgs'),
    )).thenAnswer((_) async => messagesMap);

    //act
    var messages = await sut.findMessages('111');

    //assert
    expect(messages.length, 1);
    expect(messages.first.chatId, '111');
    verify(database.query(
      'messages',
      where: anyNamed('where'),
      whereArgs: anyNamed('whereArgs'),
    )).called(1);
  });

  test('should perform database update on messages', () async {
    //arrange
    final localMessage = LocalMessage('1234', message, ReceiptStatus.sent);
    when(database.update('messages', localMessage.toMap(),
            where: anyNamed('where'), whereArgs: anyNamed('whereArgs')))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => 1);

    //act
    await sut.updateMessage(localMessage);

    //assert
    verify(database.update('messages', localMessage.toMap(),
            where: anyNamed('where'),
            whereArgs: anyNamed('whereArgs'),
            conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace))
        .called(1);
  });
}
```

In sqflite_datasource_test.mocks.dart, I can see that there is code for `update` so once again, I'm not sure why it isn't working.

```
// Mocks generated by Mockito 5.2.0 from annotations
// in rethink_chat/test/data/sqflite_datasource_test.dart.
// Do not manually edit this file.

import 'dart:async' as _i3;

import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart' as _i1;
import 'package:sqflite_common/sql.dart' as _i4;
import 'package:sqflite_common/sqlite_api.dart' as _i2;

// ignore_for_file: type=lint
// ignore_for_file: avoid_redundant_argument_values
// ignore_for_file: avoid_setters_without_getters
// ignore_for_file: comment_references
// ignore_for_file: implementation_imports
// ignore_for_file: invalid_use_of_visible_for_testing_member
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors
// ignore_for_file: unnecessary_parenthesis
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types

class _FakeBatch_0 extends _i1.Fake implements _i2.Batch {}

/// A class which mocks [Database].
///
/// See the documentation for Mockito's code generation for more information.
class MockDatabase extends _i1.Mock implements _i2.Database {
  MockDatabase() {
    _i1.throwOnMissingStub(this);
  }

  @override
  String get path =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.getter(#path), returnValue: '') as String);
  @override
  bool get isOpen =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.getter(#isOpen), returnValue: false)
          as bool);
  @override
  _i3.Future<void> close() => (super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#close, []),
      returnValue: Future<void>.value(),
      returnValueForMissingStub: Future<void>.value()) as _i3.Future<void>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<T> transaction<T>(_i3.Future<T> Function(_i2.Transaction)? action,
          {bool? exclusive}) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(
          Invocation.method(#transaction, [action], {#exclusive: exclusive}),
          returnValue: Future<T>.value(null)) as _i3.Future<T>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<int> getVersion() =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#getVersion, []),
          returnValue: Future<int>.value(0)) as _i3.Future<int>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<void> setVersion(int? version) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#setVersion, [version]),
          returnValue: Future<void>.value(),
          returnValueForMissingStub: Future<void>.value()) as _i3.Future<void>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<T> devInvokeMethod<T>(String? method, [dynamic arguments]) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(
          Invocation.method(#devInvokeMethod, [method, arguments]),
          returnValue: Future<T>.value(null)) as _i3.Future<T>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<T> devInvokeSqlMethod<T>(String? method, String? sql,
          [List<Object?>? arguments]) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(
          Invocation.method(#devInvokeSqlMethod, [method, sql, arguments]),
          returnValue: Future<T>.value(null)) as _i3.Future<T>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<void> execute(String? sql, [List<Object?>? arguments]) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#execute, [sql, arguments]),
          returnValue: Future<void>.value(),
          returnValueForMissingStub: Future<void>.value()) as _i3.Future<void>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<int> rawInsert(String? sql, [List<Object?>? arguments]) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#rawInsert, [sql, arguments]),
          returnValue: Future<int>.value(0)) as _i3.Future<int>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<int> insert(String? table, Map<String, Object?>? values,
          {String? nullColumnHack, _i4.ConflictAlgorithm? conflictAlgorithm}) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(
          Invocation.method(#insert, [
            table,
            values
          ], {
            #nullColumnHack: nullColumnHack,
            #conflictAlgorithm: conflictAlgorithm
          }),
          returnValue: Future<int>.value(0)) as _i3.Future<int>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>> query(String? table,
          {bool? distinct,
          List<String>? columns,
          String? where,
          List<Object?>? whereArgs,
          String? groupBy,
          String? having,
          String? orderBy,
          int? limit,
          int? offset}) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(
              Invocation.method(#query, [
                table
              ], {
                #distinct: distinct,
                #columns: columns,
                #where: where,
                #whereArgs: whereArgs,
                #groupBy: groupBy,
                #having: having,
                #orderBy: orderBy,
                #limit: limit,
                #offset: offset
              }),
              returnValue: Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>>.value(
                  <Map<String, Object?>>[]))
          as _i3.Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>> rawQuery(String? sql,
          [List<Object?>? arguments]) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#rawQuery, [sql, arguments]),
              returnValue: Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>>.value(
                  <Map<String, Object?>>[]))
          as _i3.Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<int> rawUpdate(String? sql, [List<Object?>? arguments]) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#rawUpdate, [sql, arguments]),
          returnValue: Future<int>.value(0)) as _i3.Future<int>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<int> update(String? table, Map<String, Object?>? values,
          {String? where,
          List<Object?>? whereArgs,
          _i4.ConflictAlgorithm? conflictAlgorithm}) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(
          Invocation.method(#update, [
            table,
            values
          ], {
            #where: where,
            #whereArgs: whereArgs,
            #conflictAlgorithm: conflictAlgorithm
          }),
          returnValue: Future<int>.value(0)) as _i3.Future<int>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<int> rawDelete(String? sql, [List<Object?>? arguments]) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#rawDelete, [sql, arguments]),
          returnValue: Future<int>.value(0)) as _i3.Future<int>);
  @override
  _i3.Future<int> delete(String? table,
          {String? where, List<Object?>? whereArgs}) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(
          Invocation.method(
              #delete, [table], {#where: where, #whereArgs: whereArgs}),
          returnValue: Future<int>.value(0)) as _i3.Future<int>);
  @override
  _i2.Batch batch() => (super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#batch, []),
      returnValue: _FakeBatch_0()) as _i2.Batch);
}

/// A class which mocks [Batch].
///
/// See the documentation for Mockito's code generation for more information.
class MockBatch extends _i1.Mock implements _i2.Batch {
  MockBatch() {
    _i1.throwOnMissingStub(this);
  }

  @override
  _i3.Future<List<Object?>> commit(
          {bool? exclusive, bool? noResult, bool? continueOnError}) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(
              Invocation.method(#commit, [], {
                #exclusive: exclusive,
                #noResult: noResult,
                #continueOnError: continueOnError
              }),
              returnValue: Future<List<Object?>>.value(<Object?>[]))
          as _i3.Future<List<Object?>>);
  @override
  void rawInsert(String? sql, [List<Object?>? arguments]) =>
      super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#rawInsert, [sql, arguments]),
          returnValueForMissingStub: null);
  @override
  void insert(String? table, Map<String, Object?>? values,
          {String? nullColumnHack, _i4.ConflictAlgorithm? conflictAlgorithm}) =>
      super.noSuchMethod(
          Invocation.method(#insert, [
            table,
            values
          ], {
            #nullColumnHack: nullColumnHack,
            #conflictAlgorithm: conflictAlgorithm
          }),
          returnValueForMissingStub: null);
  @override
  void rawUpdate(String? sql, [List<Object?>? arguments]) =>
      super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#rawUpdate, [sql, arguments]),
          returnValueForMissingStub: null);
  @override
  void update(String? table, Map<String, Object?>? values,
          {String? where,
          List<Object?>? whereArgs,
          _i4.ConflictAlgorithm? conflictAlgorithm}) =>
      super.noSuchMethod(
          Invocation.method(#update, [
            table,
            values
          ], {
            #where: where,
            #whereArgs: whereArgs,
            #conflictAlgorithm: conflictAlgorithm
          }),
          returnValueForMissingStub: null);
  @override
  void rawDelete(String? sql, [List<Object?>? arguments]) =>
      super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#rawDelete, [sql, arguments]),
          returnValueForMissingStub: null);
  @override
  void delete(String? table, {String? where, List<Object?>? whereArgs}) =>
      super.noSuchMethod(
          Invocation.method(
              #delete, [table], {#where: where, #whereArgs: whereArgs}),
          returnValueForMissingStub: null);
  @override
  void execute(String? sql, [List<Object?>? arguments]) =>
      super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#execute, [sql, arguments]),
          returnValueForMissingStub: null);
  @override
  void query(String? table,
          {bool? distinct,
          List<String>? columns,
          String? where,
          List<Object?>? whereArgs,
          String? groupBy,
          String? having,
          String? orderBy,
          int? limit,
          int? offset}) =>
      super.noSuchMethod(
          Invocation.method(#query, [
            table
          ], {
            #distinct: distinct,
            #columns: columns,
            #where: where,
            #whereArgs: whereArgs,
            #groupBy: groupBy,
            #having: having,
            #orderBy: orderBy,
            #limit: limit,
            #offset: offset
          }),
          returnValueForMissingStub: null);
  @override
  void rawQuery(String? sql, [List<Object?>? arguments]) =>
      super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#rawQuery, [sql, arguments]),
          returnValueForMissingStub: null);
}
```

If you'd like to see any other files, please let me know and I'll edit the post to include them. Please let me know what you think. Like I said, I'm a beginner so hopefully this issue is something simple.

Comment: What does `localMessage.toMap()` return?  Does it *exactly* match `{chat_id: 1234, id: 4444, from: 111, to: 222, timestamp: 2021-04-01 00:00:00.000, contents: hey, receipt: sent}`?

Comment: `update` was called with `conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace`, but your stub doesn't expect that.

Comment: How do I check what `localMessage.toMap()` returns? Sorry for such a basic question, I'm following a tutorial and very new to all this.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me. I tried commenting out `conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace` in     `//assert
    verify(database.update('messages', localMessage.toMap(),
            where: anyNamed('where'),
            whereArgs: anyNamed('whereArgs'),
            conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace))
        .called(1);` but I still get the error.

Comment: Also `localMessage.toMap()` works for database.insert, it only doesn't work for database.update

Comment: Commenting out the `verify` line won't help; that's just checking how many times your stub was called.  It will not change how the code being tested actually invokes the `update` method on your mock.  You need to fix your stub to expect `ConflictAlgorithm.replace`.

Comment: @jamesdlin, thank you so much. This fixed it. And I learned a lot. I hope you have an amazing rest of your day!

Comment: @jamesdlin Sorry if this isn't allowed, but I got a similar error for another test, and I tried to fix the stub, but everything I'm trying just gives more errors. Do you mind looking at this & letting me know what you think if you have a chance? I would be very grateful.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72512500/mockito-missingstuberror-commit-no-stub-was-found-which-matches-the-argument