# How do I import a file from the test directory to use in a lib file?

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

In an attempt to figure out an issue, I realized that my file `sqflite_datasource.dart` calls for something that is only found in the file `sqflite_datasource_test.mocks.dart`. I am trying to import the file `sqflite_datasource_test.mocks.dart` as a package to the file `sqflite_datasource.dart` so that I don't get the error anymore.

I've tried the following and they don't work:

```
import 'package:rethink_chat/test/data/sqflite_datasource_test.mocks.dart'; 
import '../test/data/sqflite_datasource_test.mocks.dart';
```

They both have red squiggly lines and if I hover over them, it asks if I want to create the file. It's not finding that it already exists.

These are the files I have:

```
│   ├── data
│   │   └── datasources
│   │       ├── datasource_contract.dart
│   │       └── sqflite_datasource.dart
│   ├── main.dart
│   └── models
│       ├── chat.dart
│       └── local_message.dart
├── test
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── sqflite_datasource_test.dart
│   │   └── sqflite_datasource_test.mocks.dart
│   └── widget_test.dart
```

I'll add the whole reason I'm trying this is because I'm having [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72499493/missingstuberror-update-no-stub-was-found-which-matches-the-arguments-of-this). I determined `update` is being found in the test file, I think because I imported the mocks file there (they're both within the test folder). But the test file calls a function in `sqflite_datasource.dart` that uses `update`, which I haven't imported the mocks file to. So I'm trying to import the mocks file there because it has the information on what `update` is. I'm a total beginner so please bear with me, it's probably a very simple solution.

Edit: I'm so confused. Some of the functions in `sqflite_datasource.dart` that use things other than "update" but similar, like "query" and "insert" work just fine. So I have no idea why "update" isn't working.

Comment: You cannot, and what you want is backwards.  If you need to share code between your `lib/` and `test/` directories, then that common code should live in `lib/`.

Comment: Hey thanks for letting me know @jamesdlin. Do you have any idea how I can solve the original issue where the test file doesn't know what update is?