# Mockito, MissingStubError: 'commit' No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito, sqflite

I'm following a messaging app tutorial that's a little outdated. I'm a beginner trying the tutorial using the most recent versions & packages. I'm getting an error in testing using Mockito. I'm such a beginner that this is likely to be a simple fix that I just don't know about.

This is the test:

```
  test('should perform database batch delete of chat', () async {
    //arrange
    final chatId = '111';
    when(database.batch()).thenReturn(batch);

    //act
    await sut.deleteChat(chatId);

    //assert
    verifyInOrder([
      database.batch(),
      batch.delete('messages', where: anyNamed('where'), whereArgs: [chatId]),
      batch.delete('chats', where: anyNamed('where'), whereArgs: [chatId]),
      batch.commit(noResult: true)
    ]);
  });
```

This is the error:

```
MissingStubError: 'commit'
No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call:
commit({exclusive: null, noResult: true, continueOnError: null})

Add a stub for this method using Mockito's 'when' API, or generate the MockBatch mock with a MockSpec with 'returnNullOnMissingStub: true' (see https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/annotations/MockSpec-class.html).
```

I can see in the mock file that there is a commit method.

I'm thinking I have to add something to `when(database.batch()).thenReturn(batch);`, for example in `database.batch()`, but what do I put there? I've tried a few things and just get more errors. And is that even the right thing to do in this situation?

Please let me know any other useful information to include, and I'll edit to include it.

Comment: The error message told you what's wrong.  You have no stub for `commit`, so you need to create add a stub for `database.commit`: e.g. `when(database.commit(noResult: anyNamed('noResult')))`

Comment: Ok, thanks so much. Where do I put that in the code? Do I put it in the test? Or in a different file? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Ok I added `when(batch.commit(noResult: true)).thenAnswer((_) async => <Object?>[]);` to the test file before the part where I was getting an error and it worked!! Thanks so much for helping me.